# Создание popup-календаря для QLineEdit в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit, qcalendarwidget, qdateedit

Для моей программы нужно сделать два поля `QLineEdit`, в которые пользователь будет вводить дату, используя для этого виджет `QCalendarWidget`, либо вводить дату вручную. 
Т.к. главное окно программы имеет адаптивные размеры, то простая вставка календаря в сетку не представляется возможной из-за того, что когда календарь скрыт, то окно программы выглядит нормально, а когда вызван календарь, то окно программы растянется на высоту календаря-это неприемлемо. 
По этой причине было решено сделать popup-календарь. Использование `QDateEdit` не подходит по причине того, что в этот виджет нельзя установить `placeholder` (ДД.ММ.ГГГГ).

Копаясь который день в интернете, я нашел интересный вариант создания popup-календаря с применением `QToolButton` и `QMenu` (в моем примере это реализовано). Для того, чтобы календарь открывался по клику на `QLineEdit`, в программе было определено действие для этого поля при фокусе по нему (полю) `self.lineEdit.installEventFilter(self)`.

То, чего я бы хотел добиться, но у меня не получается:

1. При клике по полю `QLineEdit` должен открыться календарь, но курсор должен находится в поле ввода и пользователь может вводить дату с клавиатуры (календарь не закрывается при ручном вводе), при этом также доступен ввод с календаря;
2. После того как пользователь ввел дату с календаря, в поле устанавливается выбранная дата, НО при этом курсор остается в поле для даты. Нужно, чтобы после ввода поле даты было без фокуса и без установленного курсора (при этом задумано срабатывание  сигнала `editingFinished`, вызывающего функцию валидации введенной даты);
3. Если пользователь захочет удалить или отредактировать дату, то нажатием на поле даты откроется календарь и будет возможность редактировать дату вручную или с помощью календаря (аналогично п.1);
4. Если пользователь захочет удалить дату используя `ClearButton` в `QLineEdit`, то нажав на эту кнопку откроется календарь и дата будет удалена.

*В веб-приложениях модуль popup-календаря реализован из-коробки, хотелось бы, чтобы в моей программе поведения календаря и поля даты было таким же.*

Как дополнительный вопрос: как можно в `QCalendarWidget` установить дату самому, именно не текущую дату, а произвольную (наподобие команды `setDate`), чтобы если пользователь введет дату вручную, то при успешной валидации эта дата установилась в календаре, и открыв повторно календарь, пользователь бы видел именно эту дату?

Еще вопрос до кучи: можно ли в `QMainWindow` накладывать несколько сеток `QGridLayout` одна на другую?

Минимально-воспроизводимый код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from datetime import datetime, date, time

class Menu(QMenu):
    def showEvent(self, event):
        if self.isVisible():
            button = self.parentWidget()
            if button is not None:
                pos = button.mapToGlobal(button.rect().bottomLeft())
                self.move(pos - self.rect().topLeft())
        super().showEvent(event)

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(400, 200)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QLabel("Testing LineEdit Popup")
        self.label.setFocus()
        self.toolbutton = QToolButton(popupMode=QToolButton.InstantPopup)
        self.toolbutton.setFocus()

        self.widget = QCalendarWidget()

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("ДД.ММ.ГГГГ")

        self.widgetAction = QWidgetAction(self.lineEdit)
        self.widgetAction.setDefaultWidget(self.widget)

        self.widgetMenu = Menu(self.lineEdit)
        self.widgetMenu.addAction(self.widgetAction)
        self.toolbutton.setMenu(self.widgetMenu)
        self.widget.clicked.connect(self.vrfDate)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        #self.layout.addWidget(self.toolbutton)

        self.vrfdate = self.lineEdit.text()

        self.lineEdit.installEventFilter(self)
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.dateValidator)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn:
            if obj == self.lineEdit:
                self.toolbutton.showMenu()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
            print('Hover')
            #self.label.setFocus()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut:
            print('FocusOut')
        return super(Example, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def vrfDate(self):
        self.label.setFocus()
        self.widgetMenu.close()
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.widget.selectedDate().toString("dd.MM.yyyy"))
        self.vrfdate = self.lineEdit.text()

    def dateValidator(self):
        sender = self.lineEdit
        print('sender.text()', sender.text())
        if sender.text() == '':
            sender.setText('')
            if sender == self.lineEdit:
                self.vrfdate = sender.text()
        else:
            try:
                self.formattedDate = datetime.strptime(sender.text(),'%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
                if sender == self.lineEdit:
                    self.vrfdate = self.formattedDate
                    sender.setText(self.vrfdate)
                    self.vrfdate.split('.')
                    self.widget.setSelectedDate(QDate(int(self.vrfdate[0]), int(self.vrfdate[1]), int(self.vrfdate[2]))) # как установить в календарь введенную пользователем дату?
            except ValueError:
                if sender == self.lineEdit:
                    sender.setText(self.vrfdate)


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.dateValidator()
        self.label.setFocus()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Example()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

sorry, слишком много текста и вопросов.

Попробуйте пример ниже и скажите, что не так.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SimpleDateValidator(QtGui.QValidator):
    def validate(self, text, pos):
        if not text:
            return self.Acceptable, text, pos
        fmt = self.parent().format()
        _sep = set(fmt.replace('d', '').replace('M', '').replace('y', ''))
        
        for l in text:
            # убедитесь, что набранный текст представляет собой цифру или разделитель
            if not l.isdigit() and l not in _sep:
                return self.Invalid, text, pos
        years = fmt.count('y')
        if len(text) <= years and text.isdigit():
            return self.Acceptable, text, pos
        if QtCore.QDate.fromString(text, fmt).isValid():
            return self.Acceptable, text, pos
        return self.Intermediate, text, pos


class DateEdit(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    customFormat = 'dd.MM.yyyy'
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(len(self.format()))
        self.validator = SimpleDateValidator(self)
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(self.validator)

        self.dropDownButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        layout.addWidget(self.dropDownButton)
        self.dropDownButton.setIcon(
            self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowDown))
        self.dropDownButton.setMaximumHeight(self.lineEdit.sizeHint().height())
        self.dropDownButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.dropDownButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

        self.calendar = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget()
        self.calendar.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)
        self.calendar.installEventFilter(self)
        
        # connect
        self.dropDownButton.pressed.connect(self.showPopup)
        self.dropDownButton.released.connect(self.calendar.hide)
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.editingFinished)
        self.calendar.clicked.connect(self.setDate)
        self.calendar.activated.connect(self.setDate)

        self.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())

    def editingFinished(self):
        if self.calendar.isVisible(): 
            return
        if not self.isValid():
            self.lineEdit.setText('')

    def format(self):
        return self.customFormat or QtCore.QLocale().dateFormat(QtCore.QLocale.ShortFormat)

    def setFormat(self, format):
        # принимать только числовые форматы даты
        if format and 'MMM' in format or 'ddd' in format:
            return
        self.customFormat = format
        self.setDate(self.calendar.selectedDate())
        self.calendar.hide()
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(self.format())
        self.validator.setFormat(self.format())

    def text(self):
        return self.lineEdit.text()

    def date(self):
        if not self.isValid():
            return None
        date = QtCore.QDate.fromString(self.text(), self.format())
        if date.isValid():
            return date
        return int(self.text())

    def setDate(self, date):
        self.lineEdit.setText(date.toString(self.format()))
        self.calendar.setSelectedDate(date)
        self.calendar.hide()

    def setDateRange(self, minimum, maximum):
        self.calendar.setDateRange(minimum, maximum)

    def isValid(self):
        text = self.text()
        if not text:
            return False
        date = QtCore.QDate.fromString(text, self.format())
        if date.isValid():
            self.setDate(date)
            return True
        try:
            year = int(text)
            start = self.calendar.minimumDate().year()
            end = self.calendar.maximumDate().year()
            if start <= year <= end:
                return True
        except:
            pass
        return False

    def hidePopup(self):
        self.calendar.hide()

    def showPopup(self):
        pos = self.lineEdit.mapToGlobal(self.lineEdit.rect().bottomLeft())
        pos += QtCore.QPoint(0, 1)
        rect = QtCore.QRect(pos, self.calendar.sizeHint())
        self.calendar.setGeometry(rect)
        self.calendar.show()
        self.calendar.setFocus()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        # нажмите или отпустите кнопку, когда календарь отображается / скрывается
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Hide:
            self.dropDownButton.setDown(False)
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Show:
            self.dropDownButton.setDown(True)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Down, QtCore.Qt.Key_F4):
            if not self.calendar.isVisible():
                self.showPopup()
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DateEdit()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Мне нужно: 1.чтобы в поле даты по-умолчанию был указан плейсхолдер (ДД.ММ.ГГГГ).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SimpleDateValidator(QtGui.QValidator):
    def validate(self, text, pos):
        if not text:
            return self.Acceptable, text, pos
        fmt = self.parent().format()
        _sep = set(fmt.replace('d', '').replace('M', '').replace('y', ''))
        
        for l in text:
            # убедитесь, что набранный текст представляет собой цифру или разделитель
            if not l.isdigit() and l not in _sep:
                return self.Invalid, text, pos
        years = fmt.count('y')
        if len(text) <= years and text.isdigit():
            return self.Acceptable, text, pos
        if QtCore.QDate.fromString(text, fmt).isValid():
            return self.Acceptable, text, pos
        return self.Intermediate, text, pos


class DateEdit(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    customFormat = 'dd.MM.yyyy'
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="ДД.ММ.ГГГГ")  # +++ placeholderText
        
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(len(self.format()))
        self.validator = SimpleDateValidator(self)
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(self.validator)

        self.dropDownButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        layout.addWidget(self.dropDownButton)
        self.dropDownButton.setIcon(
            self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowDown))
        self.dropDownButton.setMaximumHeight(self.lineEdit.sizeHint().height())
        self.dropDownButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.dropDownButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

        self.calendar = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget()
        self.calendar.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)
        self.calendar.installEventFilter(self)
        
        # connect
        self.dropDownButton.pressed.connect(self.showPopup)
        self.dropDownButton.released.connect(self.calendar.hide)
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.editingFinished)
        self.calendar.clicked.connect(self.setDate)
        self.calendar.activated.connect(self.setDate)

#        self.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())                                # ---

    def editingFinished(self):
        if self.calendar.isVisible(): 
            return
        if not self.isValid():
            self.lineEdit.setText('')

    def format(self):
        return self.customFormat or QtCore.QLocale().dateFormat(QtCore.QLocale.ShortFormat)

    def setFormat(self, format):
        # принимать только числовые форматы даты
        if format and 'MMM' in format or 'ddd' in format:
            return
        self.customFormat = format
        self.setDate(self.calendar.selectedDate())
        self.calendar.hide()
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(self.format())
        self.validator.setFormat(self.format())

    def text(self):
        return self.lineEdit.text()

    def date(self):
        if not self.isValid():
            return None
        date = QtCore.QDate.fromString(self.text(), self.format())
        if date.isValid():
            return date
        return int(self.text())
#
    def setDate(self, date):
        self.lineEdit.setText(date.toString(self.format()))
        self.calendar.setSelectedDate(date)
        self.calendar.hide()

    def setDateRange(self, minimum, maximum):
        self.calendar.setDateRange(minimum, maximum)

    def isValid(self):
        text = self.text()
        if not text:
            return False
        date = QtCore.QDate.fromString(text, self.format())
        if date.isValid():
            self.setDate(date)
            return True
        try:
            year = int(text)
            start = self.calendar.minimumDate().year()
            end = self.calendar.maximumDate().year()
            if start <= year <= end:
                return True
        except:
            pass
        return False

    def hidePopup(self):
        self.calendar.hide()

    def showPopup(self):
        pos = self.lineEdit.mapToGlobal(self.lineEdit.rect().bottomLeft())
        pos += QtCore.QPoint(0, 1)
        rect = QtCore.QRect(pos, self.calendar.sizeHint())
        self.calendar.setGeometry(rect)
        self.calendar.show()
        self.calendar.setFocus()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        # нажмите или отпустите кнопку, когда календарь отображается / скрывается
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Hide:
            self.dropDownButton.setDown(False)
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Show:
            self.dropDownButton.setDown(True)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Down, QtCore.Qt.Key_F4):
            if not self.calendar.isVisible():
                self.showPopup()
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DateEdit()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо за отклик! Мне нужно: 
1. в поле даты по-умолчанию должен быть установлен плейсхолдер (ДД.ММ.ГГГГ);
2. вызов календаря по клику в поле ввода;
Пока хотя бы эти вопросы закрыть.

Comment: Я попробую применить кое-что из вашего кода! Может получится хоть что-то.
Остается основной вопрос: как после вставки даты из календаря убрать курсор с `QLineEdit`?

Comment: @ВадимЛошкарев я добавил обновление, что не так в моем примере?

Comment: при клике по полю QLineEdit должен открыться календарь, но курсор должен находится в поле ввода и пользователь может вводить дату с клавиатуры (календарь не закрывается при ручном вводе), при этом также доступен ввод с календаря; После того как дата введена с календаря, календарь закрывается и курсор убирается с поля ввода (поле ввода не в фокусе)

Comment: @ВадимЛошкарев я предоставил правильное решение в другом ответе и рекомендую вам его использовать.

Answer (score 1):

я еще раз перечитал второе предложение вашего описания, а именно:
"Т.к. главное окно программы имеет адаптивные размеры,
то простая вставка календаря в сетку не представляется возможной из-за того,
что когда календарь скрыт, то окно программы выглядит нормально,
а когда вызван календарь, то окно программы растянется на высоту календаря-это неприемлемо."
и **не могу с ним согласиться**. Это не так.

Класс `Dialog` - это первое что мне попалось под руки, чтобы заполнить главное окно.

А т.к. **`QDateEdit` уже предоставляет QCalendarWidget, то календарь никуда вставлять не надо!**

Данный ответ имеет совершенно другое решение и публикуется отдельным ответом.
Я считаю, что это решение предпочтительнее и рекомендую вам его использовать.

Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons  = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()

        self.createHorizontalGroupBox()
        self.createGridGroupBox()
        self.createFormGroupBox()

        bigEditor = QTextEdit()
        bigEditor.setPlainText("Этот виджет занимает все оставшееся пространство "
                "в макете верхнего уровня.")

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.gridGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(bigEditor)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Basic Layouts")

    def createHorizontalGroupBox(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox("Horizontal layout")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        for i in range(Dialog.NumButtons):
            button = QPushButton("Button %d" % (i + 1))
            layout.addWidget(button)

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createGridGroupBox(self):
        self.gridGroupBox = QGroupBox("Grid layout")
        layout = QGridLayout()

        for i in range(Dialog.NumGridRows):
            label = QLabel("Line %d:" % (i + 1))
            lineEdit = QLineEdit()
            layout.addWidget(label,    i + 1, 0)
            layout.addWidget(lineEdit, i + 1, 1)

        self.smallEditor = QTextEdit()
        self.smallEditor.setPlainText("Этот виджет занимает около двух третей "
                                      "макета сетки. \n Смотрим соотношение `setColumnStretch`!")

        layout.addWidget(self.smallEditor, 0, 2, 5, 1)   # 0, 2, 4, 1
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 10)   
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 20)  
        self.gridGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Line 1:"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Строка 2, длинный текст:"), QComboBox())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Line 3:"), QSpinBox())
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(calendarPopup=True)
        self.menuBar().setCornerWidget(self.dateEdit, QtCore.Qt.TopLeftCorner)
        self.dateEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        
        dialog = Dialog()
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(dialog, 0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Вы не заметили в тексте самого главного: "Использование QDateEdit не подходит по причине того, что в этот виджет нельзя установить placeholder (ДД.ММ.ГГГГ)." А в остальном меня этот виджет вполне устраивает.

Да дело в том, что я не понимаю зачем вам `ДД.ММ.ГГГГ`.
Ну и ладно, надо так надо. Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons  = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()

        self.createHorizontalGroupBox()
        self.createGridGroupBox()
        self.createFormGroupBox()

        bigEditor = QTextEdit()
        bigEditor.setPlainText("Этот виджет занимает все оставшееся пространство "
                "в макете верхнего уровня.")

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.gridGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(bigEditor)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Basic Layouts")

    def createHorizontalGroupBox(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox("Horizontal layout")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        for i in range(Dialog.NumButtons):
            button = QPushButton("Button %d" % (i + 1))
            layout.addWidget(button)

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createGridGroupBox(self):
        self.gridGroupBox = QGroupBox("Grid layout")
        layout = QGridLayout()

        for i in range(Dialog.NumGridRows):
            label = QLabel("Line %d:" % (i + 1))
            lineEdit = QLineEdit()
            layout.addWidget(label,    i + 1, 0)
            layout.addWidget(lineEdit, i + 1, 1)

        self.smallEditor = QTextEdit()
        self.smallEditor.setPlainText("Этот виджет занимает около двух третей "
                                      "макета сетки. \n Смотрим соотношение `setColumnStretch`!")

        layout.addWidget(self.smallEditor, 0, 2, 5, 1)   # 0, 2, 4, 1
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 10)   
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 20)  
        self.gridGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Line 1:"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Строка 2, длинный текст:"), QComboBox())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Line 3:"), QSpinBox())
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(calendarPopup=True)
        self.menuBar().setCornerWidget(self.dateEdit, QtCore.Qt.TopLeftCorner)
        self.dateEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        
        self.dateEdit.setToolTip('<b>ДД.ММ.ГГГГ</b>')                           # +++
        self.dateEdit.installEventFilter(self)                                  # +++

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        
        dialog = Dialog()
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(dialog, 0, 0)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.label = QLabel('ДД.ММ.ГГГГ', self.dateEdit)
        self.label.setObjectName('label')
        self.label.setVisible(True)        

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):                                   
        if source == self.dateEdit and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
            self.label.setVisible(False)
        elif source == self.dateEdit and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
            self.label.setVisible(True)            
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
# +++   vvvvvvvvvvvvv     <<<----------------------------------------------------  !!!    
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        QLabel#label {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
            font-size: 9.5pt; 
        }
    """)
    
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не заметили в тексте самого главного: "Использование `QDateEdit` не подходит по причине того, что в этот виджет нельзя установить placeholder (ДД.ММ.ГГГГ)." А в остальном меня этот виджет вполне устраивает.

Comment: @ВадимЛошкарев я попробовал вам предложить еще один вариант.

Comment: вы писали: "Да дело в том, что я не понимаю зачем вам ДД.ММ.ГГГГ. Ну и ладно, надо так надо." 
Объясню: это нужно, потому что будет два поля с датой и одно из них может не заполняться, а если использовать `QDateEdit`, то дата будет отображаться всегда, и не важно будет ли это дата 01.01.1900 или еще что-то, но пользователя это будет вводить в заблуждение. Поэтому поле должно иметь признаки поля для даты (т.е. иметь плейсхолдер ДД.ММ.ГГГГ, который исчезнет, когда пользователь выберет нужную дату), но быть при этом пустым. 
Скажите, как можно установить в календаре дату, setDate не подходит?